# Is there any relationship between feign clients 'readTimeout' and configuration of hystrix.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds

Tags: spring-cloud, hystrix, feign

First of all, I'm sorry for my bad at English :)

I have a question about relationship between  feign clients 'readTimeout', 'connectTimeout' and configuration of hystrix.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds.

I have used 'thread' option instead of semaphore when setting isolation.

Below are the relevant my settings.

```yml
hystrix:
  threadpool:
    A:
      coreSize: 5
      maximumSize: 5
      allowMaximumSizeToDivergeFromCoreSize: true


feign:
  client:
    config:
      A:
        connectTimeout: 500
        readTimeout: 500
        loggerLevel: basic
```

I hope you give an answer to me.

Comment: They are only related in that the hystrix value needs to exceed the sum of the feign client values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. Hystrix's thread timeout priority is more precedes then Feign client timeout. 
[Hystrix's thread timeout](https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/wiki/images/isolation-options-640.png)

```
Test case
1. condition:
- the timeout that related to Feign: 2s
- the timeout that related to Hystrix's thread: 1s

2. result
- Feign's timeout can't be work!
```